# Where is the "Tyranny of Dragons online appendix"?

Tags: dnd-5e, published-adventures

The D&D 5e adventure *Hoard of the Dragon Queen* states that it requires the "Tyranny of Dragons appendix online" which contains some of the monster stats. However I can't seem to find this on the D&D web site. Where it it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is located in two separate places.

Here are direct links for [the appendix](http://media.wizards.com/2014/downloads/dnd/HoardDragonQueen_Supplement1.pdf), and [the printer-friendly version of the appendix](http://media.wizards.com/2014/downloads/dnd/HoardDragonQueen_Supplement1_PF.pdf).

They can be accessed from the [Hoard of the Dragon Queen product overview page](http://dnd.wizards.com/products/tabletop-games/rpg-products/hoard-dragon-queen), if those direct links change.